# Need to split string based on given numeric value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, split

I have a string like this, `Fy 2002.car.state`.

I need to split this based on value, if the value is `0` I need split like "Fy 2002","car","state" separately.If the value is `1`, I need split like this "Fy 2002.car","state".

How do I achieve this without using for loop? Thanks.

Comment: is it possible that `index = 2`? and if so, what should be the result look like?

Comment: Its really hard to understand what your expecting since there is no progressive flow in your requirement

Comment: Do you have only spaces and dots to seperate?

Comment: What “index”? What is the data structure here?

Comment: I have a string "Fy 2002.car.state", if i split this by '.' it will be splitted like ["Fy 2002","car","state"]. If i have array index as 0 means it shows "Fy 2002", if 1 means, i need string "Fy 2002.car", for 2 will be like "Fy 2002.car.state" this and so on....

Answer (score 1):

First create the array using split.
Then cut off the array using splice.
Finally join the cut items using join and put it into array.

```
function mysplit(str, index){
  var a = str.split('.')
  if(index){
    a[0] += '.' + a.splice(1, index).join('.')
  }
  return a
}
```

Other possibility is to use a reduce function.

```
function mysplit2(str, index){
  var a = str.split('.')
  if(index){
    a = a.reduce(function(p, c, i) {
      p.push(c)
      return (i <= index ? [p.join('.')] : p)
    },[])
  }
  return a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the question

- split the string
- join the first nth elements with `.`

```js
var str = "Fy 2002.car.state",
    a = str.split('.');

function split(a, index) {
    if (index) {
        a[0] +=  '.' + a.splice(1, index).join('.');
    }   
    document.write('<pre>' + index + ' ' + JSON.stringify(a, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

split(a.slice(0), 0);
split(a.slice(0), 1);
split(a.slice(0), 2);
```

Comment: yes. What i am exactly expecting. logic works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `split`

```
var str="Fy 2002.car.state";
var result= str.split('.');
```

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg5974sr/)

Comment: @ozil Let OP decide don't you think?

Comment: I think giving complete answer is more appropriate